# Disable some options of a lightning-combobox

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox

Is it possible to disable specific options of a `lightning-combobox` like one can do with the attribute `disabled` of the `option` element in standard html (example below)

```html
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option disabled>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/documentation) it does not look like SF has that feature. You have to make your own component to support this use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible if you want to use base `lightning-combobox` component.

Possible workarounds: (ordered by complexity)

- Just remove disabled options from the options attribute value.
- Use `select` component blueprint from SLDS
  with disabled attribute like you mentioned https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/select/
- Create your version of `lightning-combobox` using SLDS blueprint https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/combobox/ or look on the internet if something is already available. For example here we have working version with multiselect: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-create-the-lwc-multi-select-combobox-that-salesforce-is-still-missing-c7bf3a2850dd and looks like the `item` component can be easily updated to have `disabled` styling if specific value is passed https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/combobox/#Disabled-listbox-items

Answer (score 0):

As possible solution you can use a `lightning-button-menu` [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-menu-item/documentation)
[image]
As it has the `disabled` attribute!

[image]

And you can use it like a `lightning-combobox`,
it will just appear a little different.